# crontab day of week vs. day of month?

Tags: cron, crontab, syntax

I added this to /etc/crontab on a few different linux & freebsd systems:

```
# monthly reboot: 3rd Tuesday of every month
56 07 15-21 * 2 root /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

I want a reboot on the 3rd TUESDAY of every month.  However, all the systems rebooted on the 3rd Wednesday of this month (the 19th).

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: Thanks to Ranon's answer below, looks like the below revision will work, can anyone confirm or is there an even better way of doing it?

```
# monthly reboot: 3rd Tuesday of every month
56 07 15-21 * * root test $(date +\%u) -eq 2 && /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have a look at `man 5 crontab`.

> Note:  The  day of a command's execution can be specified by two
>   fields — day of month, and day of week.  If both fields are restricted
>   (i.e., aren't *), the command will be run  when either field matches
>   the current time.  For example, ``30  4  1,15  * 5'' would cause a
>   command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus
>   every Friday. One can, however, achieve the desired result by adding a
>   test  to the command (see the last example in EXAMPLE CRON FILE
>   below).

So your servers should restart every day from 15-21 AND each tuesday.

Have a look at the manpages' example:

```
# Run on every second Saturday of the month
0 4 8-14 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 6 && echo "2nd Saturday"
```

Comment: This seriously seems like a design bug. If I wanted every day from 15-21 AND each Tuesday I'd make two separate crontab entries. Having to resort to a separate test is an ugly hack. That said, thanks for providing a workaround!

Comment: @JensErat I believe the percent sign `%` need to be escaped to be valid crontab format.