# Cronjob runs before the scheduled time, what could be wrong?

Tags: linux, crontab

I have below crontab scheduled for Saturday that falls between days 19-23, I' m not sure why it ran on 20th (Friday).  Any guesses?

```
00 21 19-23 * 6 <command>
```

Comment: You might find some inspiration in `/etc/cron.d/mdadm` used on Ubuntu and Debian. This is how it runs the first Sunday of each month: `57 0 * * 0 root if [ -x /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray ] && [ $(date +\%d) -le 7 ]; then /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray --cron --all --idle --quiet; fi`

Comment: thanks kasperd, `0 18 * * 6 [date +\%d  -le 07] && <task>`    is working well for me, where it is required to run on first Saturday of every month.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That Cron expression translates to:

```
At 21:00 on the 19, 20, 21, 22 and 23rd of every month and every Saturday.
```

So it explicitly told cron to run on Friday the 20th. This is because of:

```
When the schedule specifies both date and weekday, they're combined with a logical OR,
i.e. the job will run if current_minute == scheduled_minute 
&& current_hour == scheduled_hour && current_month == scheduled_month && 
(current_day == scheduled_date OR current_weekday == scheduled_weekday).
```

This information is from this handy Cron tool:
http://crontab.guru/

To make your job to run on given days when it is Saturday you could use:

```
00 21 19-23 * * test $(date +%u) -eq 6 && command
```

This solution is from [crontab day of week vs. day of month?](https://superuser.com/questions/348348/crontab-day-of-week-vs-day-of-month)

Comment: Beware that `%` has a special meaning in cronjobs – it separates the command's stdin.