# Run a cronjob on every month 2nd thursday

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crontab

I want to generate a report by executing a python script. This script has to run on every 2nd thursday of a month, 3.30am . How to achieve this.

Below code might work, if the dates are fall under 8-14.

```
30 3 6-12 * 4 <script>
```

However sometimes, the days are not falling as expected and it leads to error.

Comment: "the days are not falling as expected and it leads to error" – This is not very clear. I assumed the problem is like in the linked questions. If not, then please clarify ([edit] the question) and leave me a comment below.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski updated date range.

Comment: What difference does it make? (aside from the fact your question is now incoherent). If you want to run the job only when the day-of-month and the day-of-week conditions are both true then you need an additional test, like in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/348372/432690). If you need to run the job when at least one condition is true (6-12 or Thursday) then what is the actual problem?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I just want to run the script when both condition day of week and day of month becomes true. Thanks. I got the answer from the link mentioned